# Ajax Post string to server in FormData type

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, httphandler

I would like to send any string in `FormData` type.
But I have some mistakes in my code. I can't find what this is.

below code is my .aspx code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function mscert() { 
            var certname = $("#txtname").val(); 
            var formData = new FormData(); 
            formData.append("Name", certname);                        

            var post= $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyHandler.ashx",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false, 
            data: formData, 
            cache: false
        });
            pos.done(function (data, teStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(data);
                alert("ok");
            });
            pos.fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            });
        }                 
</script>
```

And below code is `MyHandler.ashx`

```
public class MyHandler: IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        HttpPostedFile ht2 = context.Request.Files["Name"];
.
.
```

I check with breakpoint and `ht2` is always `null`.

Can anyone help ?

Note that when I send image instead of string everything is ok. At this time I can get Image on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the data in JSON format  like

```
function CallHandler() {
$.ajax({
url: "Handler/MyHandler.ashx",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: { 'Id': '10000', 'Type': 'Employee' },
success: OnComplete,
error: OnFail
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I know this, I need send in FormData type.
I know that it is possible.